# PHP SESSIONS disappear on page reload

Tags: php, session

I have been trying to create SESSIONS that are accessible from different folders on my website. These SESSIONS will be set from different folders as the case may be example: "/", "/teachers" , "/students"

What I have currently:

In my PHP file:

At the top of the page:

```
session_set_cookie_params(time() + 86400000, '/', '.mysite.com', 0, 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
session_start();
```

Where I set the SESSIONS

```
session_regenerate_id(true); 
$_SESSION['signature'] = $signature;
```

Everything seems to work fine in `/teachers` but not in `/students`. When I login in the `/students` folder, it takes me successfully to the dashboard but logs me out automatically on next refresh.

If I set the the session.save_path in PHP.ini file, the automatic logout stops but the SESSION becomes unavailable when accessed from "/" but accessible from any other folder /students, /teachers, etc

```
session.save_path = '/home/mysite/sessions'
```

What am I not getting right? Is there a problem with my setup?

Comment: do all files in all folders contain `session_start();` and session is set/not empty? see if http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php helps any

Comment: make sure you have the SAME cookie settings everywhere. you shouldn't be fiddling with them at the script level. set them in php.ini to ensure they're "global".

Comment: comments/answer given; no response. Can't give you a magic answer till we know exactly which animal we're dealing with here. you know how to ping? ok, well do if you want, I've abandoned this one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- session_start() is on all pages. Just confirmed again.

Comment: @MarcB Please can you provide me with the correct php.ini settings to ensure I do not make mistakes?

Comment: If you're running this on localhost and made changes to any `.ini`/system files, make sure you did restart all services. Did error reporting throw back anything? what does a var_dump reveal? @OguguaBelonwu

Comment: @Fred-ii- I edited the post to clearly reflect the problem. Kindly review. E_ALL doesnt throw up any error. I am testing on a live server.

Comment: Have you checked that the time of your serve is rigth? We had weird session behavior on one of our server to finally find put that the date and timezone of the server were way off. Session were epired before they were created.